# new UTF8Encoding(false) still writing utf8 BOM

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I am turning the BOM off in my code and it is still printing it in my xml document. I do not understand. I have looked into many sources and still nothing     and should just start with

my code does this is general

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(CompDir + File.Name);

AppendToFile(xmlDoc, aDataRow);

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter
    (FilePrep.CompletedDirectory + File.Name, new UTF8Encoding(false))) 
    { 
    xmlDoc.Save(writer);
    writer.Close();
    }
break;
```

and the append to file looks like this

```
private void AppendToFile(XDocument xmlDoc, DataRow aDataRow)
{
    //String StrName = aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString() + ' ' + aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();

    try
    {
        XElement foundEl = xmlDoc.Descendants("CreditScoreInfo").First();
        foundEl.Add(new XElement("CreditScore", aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2)),
                    new XElement("CreditScoreDt", aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1)));
                    //,new XElement("ScoredName", StrName)); 
    }
    catch
    {
       XElement persPolicy = xmlDoc.Descendants("PersPolicy").First();
                persPolicy.Add(new XElement("CreditScoreInfo",
                    new XElement("CreditScore", aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2)),
                    new XElement("CreditScoreDt", aDataRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1))));
                    //,new XElement("ScoredName", StrName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code to save XML seems to be fine. Please make sure that it is the only code that writes XML and whatever you use to verify first bytes actually shows file correctly (i.e. I think VS may not properly reload files in binary mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this as an alternative way:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FilePrep.CompletedDirectory + File.Name, settings))
{
    xmlDoc.Save(writer);
    writer.Close();
}
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336977.aspx

Comment: ' XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                        xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                        xws.Indent = true;
                        xws.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);'

Comment: thank you very much. code got me started and the link gave the the direction to get the rest of it.